# Serving Static Files Through Flask and Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have some static files I've been serving through Flask. On a given request, I run some processing and authentication, and then serve the file. I've been doing that using Flask's `send_from_directory`, but it looks like that caches the file for a bit, which is no good for me. I have Flask running behind nginx, so I'm open to serving partially through nginx, but I need to run processing/authentication before the file gets served.

So, the main question is, how do I serve uncached static files with Flask and nginx assuming I need to do processing/authentication in Flask before serving?

Note: I've seen answers detailing how to serve files just through nginx, but that's no good for me because I have to do processing in Flask before serving.

Comment: Authentication can be done using auth_request module http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default flask caches files that you send using send_from_directory for 12 hours. You have at least a couple of options to overcome this behavior.

You can change the config value `SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT` to something less like 1 or 0 seconds which will impact the default value used for the entire application. Or, you could pass it directly to `send_from_directory` call you do not want a cache for using the keyword `cache_timeout`.

e.g.,

```
 @app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>')
 def download_file(filename):
     return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                filename, cache_timeout = 0)
```

Or you could subclass `Flask` and override the [`get_send_file_max_age`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.get_send_file_max_age) method.